# Failed to parse supported auth schemes: The operation identifier is not valid in GitKraken

Tags: git, clone, gitkraken

I am trying to clone a repository from Beanstalk via Gitkraken but for some reasons I am
getting the following error:

**"Failed to parse supported auth schemes. The operation identifier is not valid."**

The way, I am cloning the repository is that I went to Gitkraken and followed the following steps:

1. File -> Clone Repo
2. clone

   - where to clone to
   - URL
3. Atlast, when I clicked on clone the repo.

I am getting the following error as shown in an image:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Go to Preferences - Authentication and try to reconnect to your repo. Worked for me.

(Edit) In version 8.1.1, navigate to: File -> Preferences -> Integrations then re-connect to your source provider (e.g. Github, Gitlab, Azure DevOps)

Comment: I had a similar issue with GitKraken and in my case I was using gitlab with a private repo. Preferences->Authentication worked for me thanks!

Comment: The pref menu changed and I had to Forget all Passwords (https://support.gitkraken.com/integrations/authentication/). Worked when my private repo user/pass changed, but Gitkrakken had cached my old credentials

Comment: Forget All and entering user/pass worked for me as @KyleKing said